# Best way to Strong-Type a primitive in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Following similar patterns in other languages, I would be interested in producing the most useful way to strongly-type a primitive type in Kotlin.

The rationale, of course, is to have two types which are basically primitive (e.g. strings), but which cannot be assignable to each other by mistake.

My latest attempt is given here, and I'm interested to know how can it be minimized further (can defining the derived constructor be omitted?)

```
abstract class StronglyTyped<T>{
    private var value: T
    constructor(_value: T) {
        value = _value
    }
    operator fun invoke(): T {
        return value
    }
}

class UserId: StronglyTyped<String> {
    constructor(_value: String): super(_value) {}
}

class UserName: StronglyTyped<String> {
    constructor(_value: String): super(_value) {}
}

fun main() {
    val a = UserId("this is a userId")
    val b = UserName("this is a userName")
    var c: UserName
    //c = a // <== won't compile
    c = b
    println(c())
}
```

Comment: Look up Kotlin inline classes.

Comment: @Peilonrayz what does GBP stand for?

Comment: @k314159 GBP stands for Generic Best Practice. And falls under the [LCC (Lacks Concrete Context) close reason](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8574) on Code Review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `value class`es. More information is available in the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html).

An example might look something like the following:

```kotlin
value class Password(val value: String)
```

If you want to enforce some validation on the primitive, you can do so inside the `init` block.

```kotlin
value class UserId(val value: String) {
    init {
        require(value.length == 8) { "A userId must be exactly 8 characters long!" }
    }
}
```

Note however, that this just provides compile-time type safety, because the original primitive types are used during the runtime.